# Header files for fftw missing?

Tags: c, linux, fftw

I installed a new system and all of the libraries on to it. However, I have problems with fftw. After `cmake` command I get the following error

> CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
>     Could NOT find FFTW (missing: FFTW_LIBRARIES FFTW_INCLUDES)

I can find where the FFTW libraries are (`/usr/lib64/`), but I can't find where header files for fftw are located. How can I find them? Also, for some other header files: is it safe to put a symbolic link in `/usr/includes/` instead of giving the full path in `.c` code?

Comment: Install the `fftw-dev` package, or whatever it is called on your distro..

Comment: Thanks. It works. Now I have some errors with MPI, but that is for another topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Unix command `locate` to determine the location of the FFTW header files

```
$ locate fftw3.h
/usr/local/include/fftw3.h
```

If you install FFTW 3 from [source](http://www.fftw.org/download.html) the header file `fftw3.h` should be placed in `/usr/local/include/` by default.

The FFTW header files for [FFTW 2](https://packages.debian.org/source/fftw) are contained in the package [`fftw-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/fftw-dev) and for [FFTW 3](https://packages.debian.org/source/fftw3) are contained in the package [`libfftw3-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libfftw3-dev).

---

The `/usr/local` directory is intended to contain [all the user binaries, their documentation, libraries, header files, etc....](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html) so it is ok to symlink library files in there, providing you do it correctly.